# Google sheet add on is not showing up menu after publishing app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

In google sheet add-on, I am trying to add menus and calling functions over menus.

In development mode i.e app script console It works fine, but after publishing, I can see only help menu.

I have added trigger onOpen on which I call the function which adds menu, At once It did work but some how It's not working now very strange behavior.

Following is my code

```
function onOpen(e) {
  //-- Create Menu -->
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.

  ui.createMenu('MyHire')
  .addItem('ApplicationTracker', 'ApplicationTracker')
  .addItem('EvaluationTracker', 'EvaluationTracker')
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Settings').addItem('Login', 'Login'))
  .addToUi();

}
```

Comment: It looks like there's an extra parentheses just before the .addToUi();

Comment: @Cooper It is due to the sub menu, though I have updated code.Thank you for response.

Comment: It works for me....make sure you have granted all the access

Comment: Ah yes I see much more clearly than I did last night on my Iphone.

Comment: @Ritz does user will need to give access from any settings(It asked for access while installing and I allowed for those).And my app shows not secure while installing though google reviewed it.